# How to join two different table using UNION in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the below query

```
Select sum (ABC) as ecr from table1 
Where a<>'y' or b is null and c<>'g'

Union all

Select sum(bcd) as ech from table2
```

Note: I am getting results under one column but I want to be displayed under two columns

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT sum (A.ABC) as ecr,SUM(B.bcd) as ech 
FROM table1 AS A
LEFT JOIN table2 AS B
ON B.Id = A.Id
Where A.a<>'y' or A.b is null and A.c<>'g'
```

Comment: How to join two query?? Not tables

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `cross join`

```
Select sum(ABC) as ecr,
       sum(bcd) as ech
  from table1 t1
 cross join table2
 Where t1.a <> 'y'
    or t1.b is null
   and t1.c <> 'g'
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you use `,` for `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select t1.ecr, t2.ech
from (select sum(ABC) as ecr
      from table1 
      where a <> 'y' or b is null and c <> 'g'
     ) t1,
     (select sum(bcd) as ech
      from table2 
     ) t2;
```

In any other database, you would use `CROSS JOIN`.